# Codeigniter - Same name for root directory and view conflict

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, view

Stuck into a strange situation while upgrading the website to Codeigniter.

http://website.com/download                       - View .php page 
http://website.com/download/files          - Directory

If I allow directory within the .httaccess file, view stops working. Similarly, when I disallow directory, view works but directory URL throws error.

Please help

Comment: add some relevant code pls

Answer (score 0):

U can configure in virtual host setting.

Allow directory listing.

```
<Directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/listme>
  Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

Disable directory listing.

```
<Directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/dontlistme>
  Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

Comment: Any other way to control it via .htaccess or codeigniter php script?

Comment: I've never tried but what about if u put directorylist enable .htaccess to /download/files directory.

Comment: That can work out but what would be the expression.Ye Lwein, can you please help ?

I have many directories inside download/, Is there any way to do it by expression. Rather than typing the names of each?

Comment: since it's default disallow directory listing in Codeigniter so just copy your directory listing enable .htaccess to files directory.

Options +Indexes